# Correlation Coefficient vs Kills/Death Ratio

Tags: regression, correlation

First off, I'm unfamiliar to statistics so bear with me.  I am creating a web app that does some basic analysis on player stats.  Right now I am trying to determine correlations (Pearson's correlation coefficient) and perform simple linear regression on the data.

However, I am finding something interesting and I need some help interpreting my results.

Given this matrix of data where column 1 refers to kills and column 2 refers to deaths:

```
[[ 11, 5 ],
[ 6, 4 ],
[ 4, 13 ],
[ 17, 7 ],
[ 11, 7 ],
[ 0, 6 ],
[ 11, 10 ],
[ 8, 14 ],
[ 11, 11 ],
[ 9, 6 ]]
```

I find the correlation coefficient between kills and deaths is `0.15`.  However, the normal Kill/Death ratio is equal to `1.1166666...`.  So it seems that given every death, the player has `1.116` kills, yet a low correlation between the amount of kills and the amount of deaths?

These are also the values I am getting from my simple linear regression model:

```
{ slope: 0.2777777777777778,
  intercept: 5.033333333333333,
  r2: 0.022389396381873546 }
```

I know I need more data for better results but this is all I can use for now. I also read you shouldn't attempt linear regression with a low correlation and small dataset.

I feel like I'm really misinterpreting something.

Comment: Can you edit the question to state your **goals** more clearly? For example: Do you want to *predict* kills from deaths? Or you are interested in the *ratio* itself primarily (e.g. to compare players)? Is $N=10$ the typical data set size? Do you want to do calculations as "one off" post-processing? Or update as new data comes in? etc.

Comment: @GeoMatt22. Will update the question soon...my goals are to predict kills from deaths, and N=10<= X <= 200. I want to cache every 10 recent user games because that's all I can query through the API I'm using, so there will be updates as new data comes in. I am also interested in just the ratio itself and coefficient if that is a useful metric

Comment: Correlation and ordinary regression allow for a constant term--an "intercept"--in the model.  Analyzing the mean ratio is a form of regression *without* that constant term, which is why the results can seem so different. It's even possible for the two variables to be strongly *negatively* correlated but to have a consistent, statistically significant nonzero ratio. Consider these data for (kills, deaths): (210,90), (209,91), (208,92), ..., (190,110). The correlation is $-1$ but there's a consistent kill:death ratio near 2:1 (varying only from 1.73 to 2.33).

Comment: @whuber that makes a lot of sense... Thanks for the clarification. Is pearsons correlation therefore an unreliable value for these purposes? Is there a better way to determine a correlation?

Comment: If your purpose is prediction, use some form of regression.  If you use a linear model, as you have, then you get the correlation for free: it has the same sign as `slope` and its value is the square root of `r2`.   But first, *plot your data*: a scatterplot shows these are (literally) all over the map.  There's no discernible relation.

Comment: @whuber awesome, thanks for the help. If you want the rep put your comment in an answer and I'll pick it